# Django query filter by another dataset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 User models:

1. User: Default user model:
   [image]
2. Account: Custom User model, which is an extension of the defualt user model, as I wanted to add a custom field to it called 'Status'.

[image]

The problem is that I wanted to filter the data based on the current User, so id usually do something like:

Account.objects.filter(usernmae = User).values_list('status', flat=True)

The problem is that the Account dataset doesnt have the username but they both have the same ID.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
Status = Account.objects.filter(user_id=User.objects.filter(username = user).values_list('id', flat=True)).values_list('status', flat=True)
```

But then i get the following error:

[image]

I imagine there is a way better way of doing it, if yall could help me out.

Views.py:

```
def upload_audits(request):
    form = audits_form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = audits_form()
        obj = Csv_Audit.objects.get(activated=True)
        with open(obj.file_name.path,'r') as f:
            #to clear model contents before applying new data
            auditsModel.objects.all().delete()

            reader = csv.reader(f)

            for i,row in enumerate(reader):
                if i==0:
                    pass
                else:
                    user = row[1] # gets data from CSV Table and returns username
                    Status = Account.objects.filter(user_id = request.user).values_list('status')


                    
                    
                    auditsModel.objects.create(
                
                        qs_login = user,
                        Status = Status,

                        

                    )

                    
            obj.activated = True
            obj.save()   

    return render(request,"backend/uploads.html",{'form':form})
```

Accounts.py(Model)

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(('Status'), max_length=200, default='',choices = [('Bau','Bau'),('Week 1','Week 1')])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**1 Answer:mahdi rahimi**

I tried your method with the following code:

```
Status = Account.objects.filter(user__username = user).values_list('status', flat=True)
```

Which resulted in the following error:

[image]

And then I thought of doing this:

```
Status = Account.objects.filter(user = user).values_list('status', flat=True)
```

But i got this error:

[image]

Which actually returns the usernmae but it seems to be asking for an int?

Comment: `user_id__in=User.objects.filter(...)`

Comment: Based on `username=user`, you can however likely do this more efficeint. Can you share the relevant view?

Comment: for the current user, you can use user_id=user.objects.get(username=user) or get the id from request.user data if possible.

Comment: I wrote this : Status = Account.objects.filter(user_id = request.user).values_list('status') and it populates the fields but its populating all the fields on the status of the current user, instead i want each user to have the status field that matches their username. Ive added the views.py //////By the way thank you very much for your support!

Comment: @King: can you please share your `Account` model...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ijust did, thank you very much and sorry that i forgot to share it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on my experience, you can simply join the two tables, and get what you want. roughly, it translates to this:

```
result = Account.objects.filter(user__username = user).values_list('status', flat=True)
```

or you can do two queries if you are comfortable with that.

```
found_user_id = User.objects.filter(username = user).values_list('id', flat = True)
result = Account.objects.filter(user_id = found_user_id).values_list('status', flat=True)
```

hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your input, so i tried your first method, which i believe should be correct, and then i tried : Status = Account.objects.filter(user = user).values_list('status', flat=True)

Comment: Please see the thread as I added my attempts at the bottom under 1 Answer

Comment: sorry i cant add a comment in the above section. please refrain from using upper case words for variables. "Status" here means some special word for python, and so it gives you this error. use " status " or " result " instead. tell me if it solves your problem.